# Is there a commercial license for google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, licensing

I would like to use the offline caching on google maps for Android. The terms and conditions state that I cannot use this feature as a developer, but is there a commercial option that would allow me to use it - and if so how would I go about getting a license?

I will be developing a commercial application

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Terms and Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) and perhaps [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq). You should be able to find something there. And finally, look at this [site](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps_features.html), where the differences of paid/free are pretty solid :)

Comment: cheers - that's just what I was looking for